# Ho modify authenticationManagerBean() in maven repository

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to modify authenticationManagerBean in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to expose the AuthenticationManager but this code is in .class file.
I have source jar on .m2 folder.
I modified the source jar but i don't know how i can obtain the class version compiled version of this jar... (the jar containing .class files).
Can someone help me?

```
   @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
   @Override
   public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
       return super.authenticationManagerBean();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to patch a project, try to check it out from the source code provider (e.g. github) and build it with a version number like `1.2.3-patched`. If this is not possible, create a new project from the source code and the pom.xml and work with that. Never try to manipulate the repository in `.m2`.